# Custom color kit by Style

Tags: android, themes

How create custom colors kit by themes?

- in styles.xml

  ```
   <style name="Dark" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
       <item name="blueStyled">#229</item>
   </style>
  ```
- in values-v21/colors.xml

  ```
  <color name="blueStyled">?blueStyled</color>
  ```

but app crashes when try to set this color, e.g.: `android:background="@color/blueStyled"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define your colors in *res/values/colors.xml*:

```
<color name="dark_color">#229</color>
<color name="light_color">#6161ff</color>
```

Create the attribute you're gonna use as your color in */res/attrs.xml*:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="blue_styled" format="reference"/>
</resources>
```

Define items in your styles with the same name as the name of the attribute and the desired colors as their values:

```
<style name="Dark" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
     <item name="blue_styled">@color/dark_color</item>
</style>

<style name="Light" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
     <item name="blue_styled">@color/light_color</item>
</style>
```

Use the attribute as your background:

```
android:background="?attr/blue_styled"
```

The attribute should get resolved to the appropriate color based on the theme.